# How to delete/clean a loaded data after an event

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, frontend

I want load a CSV file and send it to backend. To do that I used `react-csv-reader`. I basically load a file, and after that I push another button and send the data to backend. My problem is that after sending it to backend the file still remains as selected/uploaded. How can I remove or clean that?

My code:

```
<CSVReader
  cssClass="myCSS"
  label="Choose a CSV"
  inputId="myCSV"
  inputName="myCSV"
  inputStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
  onFileLoaded={data => handleUploading(data)}
/>
//...
const handleUploading = data => {
  setSelectedFile(data);
};
```

As I said, I have my file content into `data` and I send that to backend but the file still remains as "loaded". Is there any way to clean that?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with an `document.getElementById('myCSV').value = '` after sending it to backend. It works fine

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap this element by a `form` then you could reset it, like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form ref={ref}>
        <CSVReader
          cssClass="btn btn-default btn-sm m-t-10 waves-effect"
          label="Seleziona un file CSV"
          inputId="leadsFile"
          inputName="leadsFile"
          inputStyle={{ color: "red" }}
          onFileLoaded={(data) => {
            console.log(data);
            ref.current.reset();
          }}
        />
      <button type="button" onClick={() => ref.current.reset()}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I know that isn't the right place, but it's just a example for you

Comment: It WORKS! However, I have the submit button separatelly.. so how can I do it there? Outside the CSVReader tag there is a button with an onClick.. can I tell there to reset it?

Comment: You can add `ref.current.reset()` in everywhere you need

Comment: Yes exactly but is I add it to a button, then at the click of the button, the page refreshes.. I believe because it points to the button properties. Isn't it?

Comment: Hmm, you are using `<button type="submit">`  try to `<button type="button" onClick={() => { ref.current.submit(); ref.current.reset(); }}>` . However this will not refresh the page anymore

Comment: uhmm it doesn't help bro.. I still can see the data was selected.. While if I put it inside the CSVReader tag it works, but it clears it immediatlely